# Unknown Null Pointer Exception when adding an element to an arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

What I am trying to do is add an element to an ArrayList each time a method is called.

```
public class Dice
{
private static int x3;
private static ArrayList<Integer> totals;

public Dice()
{
totals = new ArrayList<Integer>();
}

public static void Roll()
{
int x1 = (int)(Math.random()*6)+1;
int x2 = (int)(Math.random()*6)+1;
x3 = x1 + x2;
totals.add(x3);
}
}
```

Every time the Roll() method is called, I receive a Null Pointer Error for "totals.add(x3);"

Any ideas?

Comment: In the code you posted, `Roll()` is not inside of the class `Dice`.

Comment: Have you considered returning the `int` result from `Roll()`? Also, Java method names start with a lower case letter by convention. Finally, why are you initializing your static field in an uncalled constructor?

Comment: Fixed it, that was just an error when i retyped it, not the actual problem, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have totals as static field and you are initializing it in constructor which is called when an instance is created, you need to put it in static initializer block

```
static {
    totals = new ArrayList<Integer>();
}
```

inside class body, and when you refer the fields from other class you need to specify class name because it is static fields, or make them non static and access them by creating instance

---

- [Understanding Class Members](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)
- [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Agree, there are couple of messes @Stephen

Comment: or simply, `private static ArrayList<Integer> totals = new ArrayList<Integer>();`

Answer (score 0):

You should make up your choice: either `Roll()` is static method or not. If it is static (as your code suggests) then you need to make sure `totals` is initialized when you call `Dice.Roll()`.

```
class Dice
{
private static int x3;
private static ArrayList<Integer> totals=new ArrayList<Integer>();


public static void Roll()
{
int x1 = (int)(Math.random()*6)+1;
int x2 = (int)(Math.random()*6)+1;
x3 = x1 + x2;
totals.add(x3);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (totals != null) {
    totals.add(x3);
} else {
    totals = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    totals.add(x3);
}
```